# How to make event listener with calendar icon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to make a datepicker

```html
<input type="text" name="Birth" id="calendarInput" required  class="inputField" placeholder="31.12.2001">
<input type="date" name="Birth" id="calendarHiddenInput" pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"  style="display: none">
<img id="calendarImg" src="images/calendarIcon.png">
```

When you write usual `input[type=date]`, there is a clickable calendar icon, where you can pick a date. I want to make an event listener like this:

```js
$('#calendarImg').click(function () {
    $('#calendarHiddenInput').click();
});
```

But this function doesn't work. I want a usual `input[type=text]` but with small calendar icon, that shows a calendar like `input[type=date]` when you click on it. 
P.S. When I do it, I'll pick value from `calendarHiddenInput` and paste it in `calendarInput`

Comment: You can't click something that is hidden. What is the expected behavior here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. Replace "icon" with your image or text.

```js
document.forms.form01.hiddendate.addEventListener('change', e => {
  e.target.form.date.value = e.target.value;
});
```

```css
input[type="date"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="date" />
  <label>icon<input type="date" name="hiddendate"/></label>
</form>
```

The `<label>` element can be used for focusing on an input element even if it is hidden. The date picker (if there is one) will still show up.